# problema en registro de usuarios

Tags: php, sql, visual-studio, phpmyadmin

Disculpen no se cual  puede ser el problema estoy intentando conectar el registro de un usuario a la base de datos en la tabla de usuario dentro del sistema de registro, . La validación de datos los imprime perfecto cuando coloco los datos de usuario, pero al momento de colocar las condicionales en el sistema de registro me vota registro fallido nuevamente cuando ingreso los datos de registro estos datos no son almacenados en la tabla usuario no se porque. estuve revisando pero no se que sea  ya que despues de esto no se guardan los datos en la tabla usuarios y deberia guardarlos. Para guardar los datos llamo a una función en PHP que es la siguiente:

```
?>`<?php
require_once 'models/usuario.php';

class usuarioController{ 

public function index() {
    echo "Controlador Usuarios, Accion index";
}

public function registro() {
    require_once 'views/usuario/registro.php';
}

public function save(){
    if(isset($_POST)){
        $usuario = new Usuario();
        $usuario->setNombre($_POST['nombre']);
        $usuario->setApellidos($_POST['apellidos']);
        $usuario->setEmail($_POST['email']);
        $usuario->setPassword($_POST['_password']);
        
        $save = $usuario->save();
        if($save){
            echo "Registro completado";
        }else{
            echo "Registro fallido";
        }
  
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Asumo que estas usando PDO ¿cierto?

Comment: no la conexion se esta haciendo por medio de post los atributos de registro de usuario estan con getter y setter y la funcion save esta construida en el documento usuario.php este codigo impreso es la parte controladora de usuario en el documento usuariocontroller.php podrias ayudarme?

Comment: PDO es el driver de conexión a bases de datos que existe de forma nativa en PHP (*estoy casi seguro que si es PDO lo que usas o MySQLi*), creo que no me di a entender, preguntarte esto es clave para poder indicar como debes hacer debug de tu código y poder identificar el posible error

Comment: por eso exactamente es la conexion a base de datos no me supe explicar podemos hacer una reunion por meet serian 20 minutos como para que viera el codigo

Comment: No, lo siento, toda ayuda es por medio de la plataforma, PDO (*si es que lo estás usando*) tiene un método llamado `errorInfo` que usado en tus queries te permitiría observar que esta fallando a ciencia cierta, chécalo en la doc. de PHP una vez que tengas el mensaje de error podemos seguir auxiliandote, de otro modo con lo que provees poco podemos hacer

Comment: lo tengo con la variable $error y denominado show error para else

Comment: ¿Qué hace el método `save()` de la clase `Usuario`? Por otra parte, deberías controlar los datos del POST, que usas para informar a tu clase `Usuario`. Si alguno de esos datos no es posteado, estarías al menos ante un *Undefined index*, es un simple problema del tipo Warning, pero no es bueno dejar eso fuera de control.